# Answer to question which is grammatically right

Tags: word-choice, tense

What is the answer to the following  question

> Would you be available on Fridays from 14:00-16:00?

Can I answer to this question with

"Yes I am available" or "Yes I’ll be available" ?

Which answer is better?

Answer (score 4):

Both are idiomatic.

Among very careful speakers, there may be subtle differences in meaning.

"I am available" might only mean "As of now, my schedule permits me to be available then" without any commitment to keep my schedule unchanged.

"I will be available" is a commitment to be available then.

But in everyday speech, they both represent a commitment. Nevertheless, I'd prefer "I will be available" as a more exact response to the presumed intent of the question, namely a preliminary to a request to meet or talk.